# How to use multiple scopes for Authlib

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, scopes, authlib

I am working with Authlib version 0.7. I am trying to give a client access to multiple scopes, the way I do that is on client creation I pass a string delimited by spaces as the scope (for eg 'A B'). When I generate an access token for this client, it's scope is set to 'A B'. However, when I try to access a resource protected by scope 'A' (to protect resource I have added @require_oauth('A')), I am denied access and get an http 403 error. Would appreciate any suggestions that might help me fix this.
Thanks

Comment: update: after some debugging I found out that the scope of the token is being set to 'B' and not 'A B'. I thought that by default the access tokens take the same scope as their client. Need to figure out why the scope is being chopped off

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the documentation on multiple scopes:

https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/resource-server.html#multiple-scopes

You can apply multiple scopes to one endpoint in AND and OR modes. The default is AND mode.

```
@app.route('/profile')
@require_oauth('profile email', 'AND')
def user_profile():
    user = current_token.user
    return jsonify(user)
```